# I've got a weird behaviour on req.body on put request on a specific field

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, multer, body-parser

I've created a form to save a new real estate to MongoDB, using multer for multi-part form data and body-parser.

Everything works fine except the "rooms" in the "put" (EDIT) route, which are returned as an array, instead of a single value, which makes absolutely no sense, as everything else works just fine.

I've tried to translate the data from the array to a single numerical value, but that does not work as if I try to edit the document once more the new value is pushed in the array instead of replacing the old one.

```
//EDIT PUT ROUTE
router.put("/immobili/:_id/edit", 
upload.fields([{ name: 'estateImages', maxCount: 30 }, 
{ name: 'document', maxCount: 1 }]), 
(req, res) => {

// IMAGES LOGIC SKIPPED HERE AS NOT PERTINENT

Estate.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: requestedId }, {
    rooms: req.body.rooms, //BUGGED
    squareFeets: req.body.squareFeets, //WORKS CORRECTLY
    //CALLBACK ...
}}

// result of console.log of req.body.rooms and req.body.squareFeets
rooms: [ '2', '' ],
squareFeets: 120

//EJS FORM DATA
<form action="/estates/<%= estate._id %>/edit?_method=PUT" method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
//INPUT NOT WORKING:
<input name="rooms" value="<%= estate.rooms %>"></input>
//INPUT THAT WORKS:
<input name="superficie" value="<%= estate.squareFeets %>"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Comment: can you post the full form code?

Comment: Hello Marcos, thanks a lot for your interest, so much appreciated!
It's actually a HUGE form, but I've added some other relevant fields that may make it clearer.

Comment: That form is not the same your backend code and console.log is showing, there is no `squareFeets` input, so please put the actual code. You have an issue in your form, so either you put the whole code, or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, the form is in Italian, so I must have done some translation errors, here is the full Git repository for the project if you wanna take a look!
https://github.com/ZeldOcarina/casa-lugano

Comment: The full form is in the "views" directory, it's called "immobile-edit.ejs" while this put route is called "immobili.js" and it lives in the "routes" folder.

Comment: There's no rooms field, what's the name of the field, please always post a complete question, otherwise it's hard to help you, and it's a waste of time.

Comment: I'm sorry for what has occured, the input not working in Italian is called "locali", I will try to be as thorough as possible in the next questions.

Comment: You have 2: 'locali'... inputs. Next time post the whole code.

Comment: Just noticed, I'm SO SORRY. Thanks again for your time Marcos. If you wanna put this as an answer I will accept that!

Comment: Done, created the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an array, is because you have multiple inputs with that name:

```
<input name="rooms" value="<%= estate.rooms %>"></input>

<input name="rooms" value="other-value"></input>
```

So if you don't want an array, change the input name to the second one.

Comment: Thank you SO much again and excuse me for the incomplete data! :)

Comment: No worries, next time you will know to put a complete question so you'll get a faster answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Omg I have been SO stupid, I've put two inputs with the same name value in the form, thus those values were being saved as an array.

I'm so sorry about this. Thanks for your time!